# Can you install both Vim 7 and Vim 8 on CentOS 7.9?

Tags: linux, installing

I teach classes that cover both Vim 7 and Vim 8.  Is it possibly to install Vim 7 and Vim 8 together on CentOS?  If so, how?

Everything I've have looked at so far covers updating Vim 7 to Vim 8.
I need both environment for teaching purposes.

Comment: There are a few ways to do it. You could build Vim 7 from source and install it in parallel, or you could use a container image (for example, a CentOS 7 container) and run Vim 7 from there. But I see little point in doing anything with Vim 7 at this point, since the only distribution that still ships it (CentOS 7/RHEL 7) has already reached end of full maintenance...

Comment: I would use the system vim (e.g. CentOS 7 comes with Vim 7 according to https://repology.org/project/vim/versions) and compile my own Vim version 8 below $HOME

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@christian-brabant has the gist of it. At least one of them needs to be an installation outside of your package manager. Of course, if you are using an add-on package manager like conda, you can probably find them and stick them in different (virtual) environments.

*To do it yourself.*

Having multiple versions of software on a system only really requires, that those versions are installable and having a place to put them (it sounds pedantic but it is true). For Vim one way you can install both versions yourself is by following the instructions at https://www.vim.org/download.php#unix in different directories

for example

```
mkdir -p vim/8 && cd vim/8
git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git
git checkout <myFavorateVim8tag>
```

and follow build instructions for 8 (Take a look at the README and `.configure --help` to get started)
then if you'd like do the same for 7

```
mkdir -p vim/7 && cd vim/7
git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git
git checkout <myFavorateVim7tag>
```

*The main gotcha is making both accessible*, depending on what else is going on you have lots of options,  however in this case, since they are primarily interactive programs the cleanest option might be to [alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(command)) them to different names.

Comment: Or add links to the programs like vim7 and vim8 in your PATH